# How to select the smallest subset of numbers from a set which add up to a target?

Tags: r, recursion, combinatorics

I looked a lot for this question on this site but I couldn't find one to solve this.

I have a number, which is the target.

I have a list of numbers which always has some zeros in it. These values are indexed, such as

```
a<-c(0,0,110,120,200,250,300,0,0,200,330,0,0,400)
b<-1:14
data<-cbind(b,a)
target<-870
```

Now I want it to select the smallest subset possible from `data$a`, lets call it `c` where the `sum(c)` is greater than or equal to 870. I don't know how recursion works very well, but I think it is to be done using it. This is similar to the knapsack problem, but here the capacity has to be exceeded by as minimal a value as possible, the profit/weights of the knapsack objects here being all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

```
inds <- sort(data$a, decreasing = TRUE)
inds[1:which.max(cumsum(inds) > target)]
#[1] 400 330 300
```

`sort` the `data` in `decreasing` order, find the first index where values passes the `target` and subset the values.

**data**

```
a <- c(0,0,110,120,200,250,300,0,0,200,330,0,0,400)
b <- 1:14
data <- data.frame(b,a)
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. I haven't used `which` before, that's useful to learn.

Answer (score 0):

We can `order` the data in descending, then get the cumulative sum of it, compare it with the 'target' get the maximum index and subset the ordered vector

```
i1 <- data[,"a"][order(-data[, "a"])]
i1[seq_len(which.max(cumsum(i1) > target))]
#[1] 400 330 300
```

#### data

```
a <- c(0,0,110,120,200,250,300,0,0,200,330,0,0,400)
b <- 1:14
data <- cbind(b,a)
target <- 870
```